# Change current time of video player on scroll depending on height of content

Tags: javascript

I have a background video (html5 video element), fixed position width and height 100% with some text on it. When I scroll down, the video has to fast forward and the speed has to depend on how long my content (text) is. So the video will be at its end when you scrolled to the bottom.

I found this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GxDJg

And I have this so far:
https://codepen.io/rluijten/project/editor/AOywwy/

```
const accelAmount = 0.01;
const bounceAmount = 0.91;    
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const main = document.querySelector('main');

let scrollPos = main.scrollTop / 30;
let targetScrollPos = scrollPos;
let accel = 0;

video.pause();

main.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  targetScrollPos = main.scrollTop / 30;
});

setInterval(() => {
  // accelerate towards the target:
  accel += (targetScrollPos - scrollPos) * accelAmount;

  // clamp the acceleration so that it doesnt go too fast
  if (accel > 1) accel = 1;
  if (accel < -1) accel = -1;

  // move the video scroll position according to the acceleration and how much bouncing you selected:
  scrollPos = (scrollPos + accel) * bounceAmount + (targetScrollPos * (1 - bounceAmount));

  // update video playback
  video.currentTime = scrollPos;
  video.pause();
}, 40);
```

Now I'm trying to make the height of my content equal to the duration of my video. But I don't really have an idea to achieve this. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should change the scroll step rather.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const video = document.getElementById('video');
    const main = document.querySelector('main');

    let targetScrollPos = main.scrollTop;
    let targetScrollMax = main.scrollHeight;
    let step = 0.1;
    let buffer = [];
    let playing = false;

    video.pause();

    function playVideo(pos) {
      if (playing) {
        return buffer.push(pos);
      }
      playing = true;

      var dt = pos - video.currentTime > 0 ? 1 : -1,
        sid = setInterval(() => {
          video.currentTime += dt * step;
          video.pause();

          if (dt > 0 ? video.currentTime >= pos : video.currentTime <= pos) {
            video.currentTime = pos;
            video.pause();
            if (buffer.length) {
              playing = false;
              playVideo(buffer.pop()); // just last one is relevant
              buffer = [];
            }
            playing = false;
            clearInterval(sid);
          }
        }, step * 1000);
    }

    main.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
      playVideo(video.duration * main.scrollTop / main.scrollHeight);
    });
```

```css
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    main {
      overflow: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .video-container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 0;
    }

    .video-container__video {
      position: absolute;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .content-block {
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      padding: 50px 60px 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .content-block:first-child {
      margin-top: 150px;
    }

    .content-block__title {
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .content-block__text {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
```

```html
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>Video Scroll experiment</title>

    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="video-container">
        <video id="video" class="video-container__video">
                <source src="https://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
      </div>

      <main class="main">
        <div class="content-block">
          <p class="content-block__text">
            Applications for September 2017 entry are now closed. Please see the FAQ section for application deadlines.
          </p>

          <p class="content-block__text">
            A unique course in the field of theatre and performance practice, this one-year MA course allows students with a strong, demonstrable background in performance to re-examine and broaden their skills in a truly experimental and highly collaborative framework.
          </p>

          <p class="content-block__text">
            The emphasis throughout the year is on devised and ensemble work, as you will advance your understanding of performance from a post-Stanislavski standpoint.
          </p>

          <p class="content-block__text">
            The course, validated by Kingâ€™s College London, one of the worldâ€™s top 20 universities, explores non-mainstream theatre craft internationally. Read about some of graduates in the downloadable PDF
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block">
          <p class="content-block__text">
            The course is built around three strands:
          </p>

          <p class="content-block__text">
            Acting and Performance: Practice and Methodology - Working from the foundation of the Stanislavski â€˜systemâ€™, you will be introduced to the approaches and responses of later practitioners, including Brecht, Copeau, Meyerhold, and Grotowski. International
            historical context is given through exploring the improvisational and physical practice, developments in experimental theatre internationally, new writing, and performance since the early 20th Century. Development of Performance - This dual aspect
            of the course builds on your strengths and skills, whilst improving areas where you are less experienced. The first strand supports you as you refine and improve your understanding of how to develop as an individual within an ensemble environment.
            The second covers vocal and physical performance training, supplemented by Commedia, creative writing, improvisation, and singing. Scene Study - Scene study is woven throughout the course and provides a forum for you to develop and experiment
            with the techniques you are learning.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block">
          <h2 class="content-block__title">Course Details</h2>
          <p class="content-block__text">
            Our full time, three-year BA in Acting (conservatoire training) develops a high level of technical facility, flexibility, individuality and imagination. The training provides skills in acting, voice, singing and movement, and students apply these skills
            in a wide variety of media including theatre, television, film and radio.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block">
          <h2 class="content-block__title">The Program</h2>
          <p class="content-block__text">
            The training is classically based because we believe this provides the best foundation for acting in any form or media. However, the training also includes a thorough grounding in contemporary plays and styles as well as classes in camera and microphone
            technique. Your work will be continuously assessed with extensive individual feedback through regular sessions, written reports, and one-to-one tutorials.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block">
          <h2 class="content-block__title">The Program</h2>
          <p class="content-block__text">
            The training is classically based because we believe this provides the best foundation for acting in any form or media. However, the training also includes a thorough grounding in contemporary plays and styles as well as classes in camera and microphone
            technique. Your work will be continuously assessed with extensive individual feedback through regular sessions, written reports, and one-to-one tutorials.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block">
          <h2 class="content-block__title">The Program</h2>
          <p class="content-block__text">
            The training is classically based because we believe this provides the best foundation for acting in any form or media. However, the training also includes a thorough grounding in contemporary plays and styles as well as classes in camera and microphone
            technique. Your work will be continuously assessed with extensive individual feedback through regular sessions, written reports, and one-to-one tutorials.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block">
          <h2 class="content-block__title">The Program</h2>
          <p class="content-block__text">
            The training is classically based because we believe this provides the best foundation for acting in any form or media. However, the training also includes a thorough grounding in contemporary plays and styles as well as classes in camera and microphone
            technique. Your work will be continuously assessed with extensive individual feedback through regular sessions, written reports, and one-to-one tutorials.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block">
          <h2 class="content-block__title">The Program</h2>
          <p class="content-block__text">
            The training is classically based because we believe this provides the best foundation for acting in any form or media. However, the training also includes a thorough grounding in contemporary plays and styles as well as classes in camera and microphone
            technique. Your work will be continuously assessed with extensive individual feedback through regular sessions, written reports, and one-to-one tutorials.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block">
          <h2 class="content-block__title">The Program</h2>
          <p class="content-block__text">
            The training is classically based because we believe this provides the best foundation for acting in any form or media. However, the training also includes a thorough grounding in contemporary plays and styles as well as classes in camera and microphone
            technique. Your work will be continuously assessed with extensive individual feedback through regular sessions, written reports, and one-to-one tutorials.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block">
          <h2 class="content-block__title">The Program</h2>
          <p class="content-block__text">
            The training is classically based because we believe this provides the best foundation for acting in any form or media. However, the training also includes a thorough grounding in contemporary plays and styles as well as classes in camera and microphone
            technique. Your work will be continuously assessed with extensive individual feedback through regular sessions, written reports, and one-to-one tutorials.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block">
          <h2 class="content-block__title">The Program</h2>
          <p class="content-block__text">
            The training is classically based because we believe this provides the best foundation for acting in any form or media. However, the training also includes a thorough grounding in contemporary plays and styles as well as classes in camera and microphone
            technique. Your work will be continuously assessed with extensive individual feedback through regular sessions, written reports, and one-to-one tutorials.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block">
          <h2 class="content-block__title">The Program</h2>
          <p class="content-block__text">
            The training is classically based because we believe this provides the best foundation for acting in any form or media. However, the training also includes a thorough grounding in contemporary plays and styles as well as classes in camera and microphone
            technique. Your work will be continuously assessed with extensive individual feedback through regular sessions, written reports, and one-to-one tutorials.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block">
          <h2 class="content-block__title">The Program</h2>
          <p class="content-block__text">
            The training is classically based because we believe this provides the best foundation for acting in any form or media. However, the training also includes a thorough grounding in contemporary plays and styles as well as classes in camera and microphone
            technique. Your work will be continuously assessed with extensive individual feedback through regular sessions, written reports, and one-to-one tutorials.
          </p>
        </div>
      </main>

      <footer class="footer"></footer>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Is there any chance to make this go a little smoother. Right now it flashes all the time when you scroll.

Comment: when you scroll down probably yes, when you do it backwards I think it will always have a gappy feeling :) I am trying to make it smoother already but I don't know if I will succeed.

Comment: I have updated my answer with something that I think is closer of what you expect to get in visual context ;)